Flattening coupled trigons while keeping edge lengths
I'm in the process of turning a low poly trigon deer bust into parts that will be cut by a CNC plasma and later bent and welded together.
I'm trying to speed up the process of laying these out along a metal sheet(plane) while keeping edge lengths completely unchanged.

These parts with numbers on them are either 2-coupled, or 3-coupled trigons.

Any experts here who know how to keep edge lengths the same while only flattening out the angles between the planes?



Right now I'm using a painful method of manually eyeballing the flatness of the parts while rotating around the edge axes. Thanks for ANY help, cheerios!

There used to be a paperceaft addon for Blender specifically for this type of task. Maybe it can help here.

So you want all those pairs/triples of triangles to be separated?

I started with Suzanne and applied a simple node tree to split all its faces (quads) and then triangulate the quads into triangles:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Then I manually removed all but top-head faces of Suzanne, as well as split one mesh island's triangles, and join them with neighboring islands (operation marked with arrows), so that I have two islands consisting of 3 triangles. Below a node tree design to view this topology, by scaling islands down and coloring them:

Imgur mirror
You can now UV unwrap the islands and position geometry onto the UV coordinates:

 Imgur mirror
In the process the mesh is scaled to fit the normalized 0..1 UV space, but you can just compare the length of the first edge before/after and scale by that:

Obviously you can apply the process without Geometry Nodes, by manually splitting, uv unwrapping checking edge length before/after and scaling accordingly.
